# fsockopen with variables not working

Tags: php

Am newbie to this, so might be asking a very simple question. Trying to run a simple php program using `fsockopen` with variables. However it's failing with error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

**My code:**

```
$A = 11.22.33.44
$H = sprintf('"%s"', $A);
echo "host \n", $H;
$Y = '1234';
$Z = (int)$Y;
echo "port \n" , $Z;
$fp = fsockopen($H, $Z, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

It works fine with hard-coded values like `fsockopen("11.22.33.44", 1234, $errno, $errstr, 30)`. Please suggest the fix.

Comment: Is that your actual code? `$A = 11.22.33.44` is bad syntax. Also you shouldn't quote the IP in the sprintf. Just write `$H="11.22.33.44";` or `$H=sprintf("%s",$A);`

Comment: Nopes, Its just an example. Am picking up these variables from html screen. problem is with fsockopen() function.

Comment: Obviously since it works with hard-coded parameters and not with what you pass it the problem is what you're passing it. try `var_dump([$H,$Z])` and compare the result to what you are manually passing ( i.e. `var_dump(["11.22.33.44", 1234])`)

Comment: Thanks so much. it helped me identified the issue and its working.